# Caret Error for TrainControl, method="repeatedCV"

Tags: r, r-caret

Using the following code

```
trnCtrl=trainControl(method='repeatedCV', number=10, repeats=5)
```

I get the error

> Warning message: `repeats` has no meaning for this resampling method.

Even stranger, it worked fine until I did a reinstall of Caret.  Note that I have already removed R, and reinstalled all packages 2x...

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that this is an old question but after looking through the Caret source code all I can deduce is that the problem is occurring when declaring the sampling method.

The following snippet has been pulled directly from the `Caret` repo:

```
    if(!is.na(repeats) & !(method %in% c("repeatedcv", "adaptive_cv")))
        warning("`repeats` has no meaning for this resampling method.", call. = FALSE)
```

My guess is the condition is failing when evaluating the method. You've specified the method as `repeatedCV` whereas it's actually named `repeatedcv`.

Again I appreciate that this question is old and it could well be the name has changed since 2013. In which case, ignore this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error and the reason was I typed "repeatecv", wrong method.

When I changed to right name, "repeatedcv" it worked.

Try,

trnCtrl=trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=10, repeats=5)